# Safari: edit and save local storage value

Tags: javascript, safari, local-storage

I am working in Safari 8.0.4 with some local-storage variables. I can see the values in the web inspector, select/copy and delete them. However if I try to edit them, the changes are not kept after a page refresh. The input field behaves a little strangely, I can't seem to deselect it any way apart from by hitting escape (return key or clicking outside does nothing).

Is this a known bug, and is there any way to manually edit a local storage value in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

I was unsuccessful directly editing within the resource inspector, but I did successfully change local storage values via Safari's Javascript console.  (just below the resource inspector)

Use a command like this:

```
   localStorage.setItem(key, value)
```

It is less convenient than direct editing, but it does work.